# Any Sencha touch2 examples about REST proxy?

Tags: rest, sencha-touch-2

Can anybody please provide some examples about REST proxy in sencha touch 2~~ ?
I need to study it but didnot find any example about it

Comment: How about http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest

Comment: Please tell me when to use proxy JsoP and when Rest?

Comment: Please accept one of the answer below or provide more details about your issue if they didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

According to TDeBailleul's comment, this is a good place for you to start. I think that it's detailed enough:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest

About REST vs JSONP. Essentially, REST is a specific type of Ajax.

JSONP is actually Cross-domain AJAX. They are not the same in essence.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one for ExtJS - the data package is very similar between touch and extjs.

http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/restful/restful/